# using wp_get_recent_posts with specific page template

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get 10 recent post and pages using `wp_get_recent_posts()`. I want to show recent post and recent pages of specific template. below is my code but I am not getting any post.

```
$lastupdated_args = array(
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'post_type' => array('page', 'post'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                                'value' => 'tutorial.php', // template name as stored in the dB
                                )
                        ),
    );
//Loop to display 10 recently updated posts
$recent_posts  =  wp_get_recent_posts( $lastupdated_args );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change the logic a little bit. Now instead of using a `template` I have created a `custom post type` and the same in `post_type` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$lastupdated_args = array(
 'numberposts' => 10,
 'orderby' => 'post_date',
 'post_type' => array('page', 'post'),
 'post_status' => 'publish',
  'meta_key'='_wp_page_template',
  'meta_value' ='tutorial.php'
   );
  //Loop to display 10 recently updated posts
  $recent_posts  =  wp_get_recent_posts(   $lastupdated_args );
```

Comment: Thanks @Osama, I added this code and only get the list of pages no posts

Comment: 'post_type'=>array('post','page');

Comment: I changed the sequence to `'post','page'`, but no luck, same result.

Comment: 'post_type'=>'post'; search as post then use if statement before the loop to display only page and post by discard category and other types

Comment: I removed `page`, then no result

Comment: Do you have post in your database ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141810/discussion-between-aje-and-osama).